# Microsoft VBA Type Error: How to use .cells instead of range.value for isEmpty()

Tags: excel, vba, typeerror

I'm new to VBA so this might be a bit of an easy or tedious fix, but I'm trying to get the following line of code to work:

```
For Each orgnameB in rngOrgList
If  IsEmpty(Worksheets("Org List").Cells(orgnameB, "I")) = False Or _
    IsEmpty(Worksheets("Org List").Cells(orgnameB, "J")) = False Or _
    IsEmpty(Worksheets("Org List").Cells(orgnameB, "K")) = False Then

        Worksheets("Quickbooks").Cells(start.row, "G").Value = "The following discounts have been applied:"

End If
```

I get a type error, I think because you're supposed to use range references with rng.Value, and not cell references, for the isEmpty() function. Is there any way to get around this issue? How would you recommend solving this? Thank you!!

Comment: What is `orgnameB`? And `rngOrgList`? One can use `Cells` with `IsEmpty`, e.g. `? IsEmpty(Cells(1, "I"))` in the Immediate Window. Something else is the issue.

Comment: For reference, a `Cells` call returns a `Range` object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells

Comment: Also, `.Cells` requires two numbers and you are passing in at least one letter here.

Comment: @HackSlash - actually the second argument can be the column index or letter (in fact there's a downvoted/deleted answer to this question that mistakenly assumed `Cells` only used numbers). As noted in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.item#remarks).

Comment: Alternatively: `If  Application.CountA(Worksheets("Org List").Cells(orgnameB, "I").Resize(1, 3)) >0 Then`